# Is there a reason I can't get the correct distance of an object from a distance sensor outside the sonar function?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm developing a simple project where I need to integrate different sensors and actuators to make them able to interact with themselves but I'm  having a problem right at the start of the process. My first goal was to make a distance sensor work correctly by showing me the correct distance of an object placed in front of it. Depending of the value of said distance, an actuator like a LED would have different behaviors.
I'm using Tinkercad to test the distance sensor first, so this is my current design:

[image: Arduino with Distance Sensor design]

Ant this is my current code:

```
#define ECHO 9
#define TRIG 8
#define TRIGGER_GAP 100

int distance;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(TRIG, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()

{
  sonar();

  //Wrong Outputs
  //Serial.println(distance);


}

void Trigger(byte pin){
  digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
}


void sonar(){
  static const int REPOUSO=0, ESPERA_ECHO=1, ESPERA_ECHO_HIGH=2, ESPERA_ECHO_LOW=3;
  static int state=REPOUSO;
  static unsigned long t0=millis(),t0echo;
  unsigned long t1, t1echo;
  
  switch(state){
    case REPOUSO:

t1 = millis();

if(t1 - t0 >= TRIGGER_GAP){
  Trigger(TRIG);
  t0 = t1;
  state = ESPERA_ECHO;
}
break;

case ESPERA_ECHO:
if (digitalRead(ECHO)==LOW){
  Trigger(TRIG);
  state = ESPERA_ECHO_HIGH;
}
break;

case ESPERA_ECHO_HIGH:
if(digitalRead(ECHO)==HIGH){
  t0echo = micros();
  state = ESPERA_ECHO_LOW;
}
break;

case ESPERA_ECHO_LOW:
t1 = millis();
if(digitalRead(ECHO)==LOW){
  t1echo = micros();

  distance = (t1echo- t0echo)/58.0;
  //Correct Outputs
  Serial.println(distance);

  state = REPOUSO;
  break;

}

else{
  if(t1-t0>=TRIGGER_GAP){
    state = REPOUSO;
  }
 
}

break;
  }
  
}
```

The distance variable is supposed to be global because it will be the one that will be given to an actuator like a LED to affect its behavior. When I use the Serial.println(distance) function after the "Correct Outputs" commented line, the distance values make sense and change accordingly with the changes of the object's position, but if I comment that Serial.println() line and uncomment the one after the line that says "Wrong Outputs", the distance values make no sense and sometimes are still the same even if I move the object, which makes it impossible for an actuator to act correctly because the distance values are also incorrect. I've gone through this code many times and tried to search for some similar problems but unsuccessfully.

Is there a reason why somehow the distance variable only has the right values only when I print them inside the if clause where the comment "Correct Outputs" is? Because even if I print the variable inside the case "ESPERA_ECHO_LOW", the console will output the same wrong values just like when I print after the sonar() line inside the loop function.

Sorry if its confusing, but the fact that the distance variable isn't outputting the correct distance values makes it impossible for me to continue to develop this project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to replace the print in the function with a delay(1) and print in loop()

Comment: @Juraj I tried that but I still get the wrong values